# Will a USB to PS/2 adapter come with the benefits of a PS/2 to PS/2 connection?

Tags: usb, keyboard, adapter, ps2, ps2-keyboard

Will the benefits of ultra low latency "forces the cpu to deal with the ps/2 input" exist with a USB to PS/2 adapter or will the adapter be a limiting factor?

Comment: Its worth consider if we're talking about *active* or *passive* adaptors. For those in the keyboard community though - this question's pretty clear. Some folks really do prefer PS/2 for better potential response times and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PS/2 is interrupt driven while USB depends on the host to poll attached devices....so you'll lose the latency benefit of PS/2 simply because the adapter uses USB.

Comment: @PolisP - If you use a USB to PS/2 adapter you would indeed require a PS/2 device.  If you don’t want to use a PS/2 keyboard don’t use the adapter

Answer (score 2):

A USB to PS/2 adapter (like the [little green ones](https://www.amazon.ca/Logitech-501215-0004-USB-PS-Adapter/dp/B00E9H3YKI) Logitech packs with some keyboards) is only compatible with specific keyboards!

These keyboards support both USB and PS/2 *natively* and switch modes when the adapter is connected.

Using this adapter is no different from using a PS/2 keyboard, because keyboards that work with the adapter *are* PS/2 keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I used such an adapter (no PS/2 or Parallel ports) the adapter did not speed up anything to any measurable degree. Just the same is how I would put it.